# The acceptance of the counter must change span - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day! Need help with dynamically changing the span when changing the attribute of the counter (aria-valuenow) The span values ​​must be in the array itself.

The **jQuery** code to change the counter

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
var arrText = ["450 гр.", "900 гр.","2270 гр.","4540 гр."];

$(function() {
    $("#spinner-tovar-1-gramm").textSpinner({
        values: arrText
    });
});

});
```

**HTML Counter Code**

```
 <span class="ui-spinner ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<input id="spinner-tovar-1-gramm" value="0" readonly="" aria-valuenow="1" autocomplete="off" class="ui-spinner-input" role="spinbutton">
<input class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up" id="buttonup" type="button" value="">
<input class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down" id="buttondown" type="button" value="">
</span>
```

For example, if the attribute of the counter aria-valuenow = "0", then the text span will contain 1000, if = "1", then 2000, etc. And all this is happening dynamically

Help Please

[image]

Comment: `$(function () {})` and `$(document).ready(function () {})` are exactly the same thing... Do not nest them, it does not make any sense.

Comment: Thanks :) Can u help me?)

Comment: I'm currently reviewing posts of newcomers, so I'm not available at the moment... :)